# How to avoid vtable-lookups in production, and still be able to mock extensively in unit-tests?

Tags: c++, performance, unit-testing, mocking, vtable

In languages such as C# I often let my classes depend on interfaces instead of concrete classes, even when there is only one 'real' implementation. This is to make unit-testing easier (by creating mocks).

When programming in C++ I want maximum performance, and still use TDD and mocking. Is there a way of achieving both? That is, to be able to mock when testing, and still have direct concrete calls in production code?

How can this be achieved in C++?

Comment: C++ offers not only dynamic polymorphism, i. e. late binding with vtable-lookups, but also static polymorphism using templates. This of course can lead to longer compile times since template implementation need to reside in the header file.

Comment: My issue with wanting to be able to mock everything for testing is that dependency injection makes some interfaces huge, and hard to follow what the code is actually doing when every other function call involves jumping around figuring out which component is really being used. Templates can solve the virtual call issue, but they don't make your code any nicer. It also means the code you are testing is that little bit further from your production code.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler will optimize away the vtable lookup when it sees that there is only one implementation of the virtual class? Or perhaps there is some trick one can use to swap the pointer to abstract class with a pointer to the concrete class when building for production? Macros?

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/rKAYRD). With gcc 9.2 and -O2 there is no difference between polymorphic call and normal function call. Only the construction of polymorphic class takes one CPU instruction more.

Comment: @Ptaq666: That's because GCC is smart enough not to use a polymorphic call in your example. It figures out the run-time type already at compile time. This is possible because there's no dependency on any external factor.

Comment: @unique_ptr "_when it sees that there is only one implementation of the virtual class?_" You would need to see the complete program for that, in general (exception: when a base is defined in one single TU in an anon namespace).

Comment: @unique_ptr "_implementation of the virtual class_" Classes are "virtual", functions are. Classes can be polymorphic and abstract; base classes can be virtual in some derived class.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of interface and runtime polymorphism:

```
struct IService
{
    virtual ~IService() = 0;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    // ...
};

class C
{
public:
    explicit C(IService& service) : service(service) {}

    void DoJob() { /*..*/ service.foo(); /*..*/ }
    // ..
private:
     IService& service;
};
```

In Production:

```
struct Service : IService
{
    void foo() override;
    // ...
};

Service service;
C c(service);
c.doJob();
```

In Test

```
struct ServiceMock : IService
{
    void foo() override;
    // ...
};

ServiceMock service;
C c(service);
c.doJob();
```

You might use template for that:

```
// No interface to provide requirement, so document it
// TService must have `foo()`, ...
// or wait for C++20 concept
template <typename TService>
class C
{
public:
    explicit C(TService& service) : service(service) {}

    void DoJob() { /*..*/ service.foo(); /*..*/ }
    // ..
private:
     TService& service;
};
```

Calling code is mostly similar to runtime code:
- no inheritance.
- More verbose before C++17 though. :/

In Production:

```
struct Service
{
    void foo();
    // ...
};

Service service;
C c(service); // or before C++17 C<Service> c(service);
c.doJob();
```

In Test:

```
struct ServiceMock
{
    void foo();
    // ...
};

ServiceMock service;
C c(service); // or before C++17 C<ServiceMock> c(service);
c.doJob();
```

but that kind of template is as contagious than `const` (Calling testable code should be template too).

And before C++17, it seems really too verbose:

```
OuterService<ServiceA<Service1, Service2>, ServiceB<Service1, Service2>> outer(serviceA, servceB);
// versus
// OuterService outer(serviceA, servceB);
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, there is no dynamic call (vtable lookup) when the dependencies are passed by reference? Even if that reference is to an abstract type such as IService?

Comment: You have dynamic dispatch with `IService` (with either reference or pointer), but not with template version.